# Gameobject does not clamp but rather jitters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, clamp, jitter

I am trying to clamp the value of y for my game object to be 4 and -4 but it keeps jumping to the ymax and ymin. and the only reason i can think of is because of the last line code. i am only clamping the y values because the x and z values are not changed in the game. the game is similar to pong.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movement1 : MonoBehaviour 
{

public Vector3 Pos;
void Start () 
{
    Pos = gameObject.transform.localPosition;
}

public float yMin, yMax;
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
        transform.Translate (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 10);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
        transform.Translate (Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 10);
    }

    Pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(Pos.y,yMin,yMax);
    gameObject.transform.localPosition = Pos;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pos.y assignment never happens, because you can't change just the y-value; you have to make a new Vector3. Try the following:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movement1 : MonoBehaviour 
{

public float yMin, yMax; // be sure to set these in the inspector
void Update () 
{

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
        transform.Translate (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 10);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
        transform.Translate (Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * 10);

    }

    float clampedY = Mathf.Clamp(transform.localPosition.y,yMin,yMax);
    transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (transform.localPosition.x, clampedY, transform.localPosition.z);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize any values for the `yMin`, `yMax`.

Also, you should put an `else if` for the second `Translate`, otherwise pressing both could cause jitters.

But really, it should be more like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movement1 : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Vector3 Pos;
    public float speed = 10f;
    public float yMin = 10f;
    public float yMax = 50f;

    void Update () 
    {
        Pos = gameObject.transform.localPosition;

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W))
            Pos += (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S))
            Pos += (Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * speed);

        Pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(Pos.y,yMin,yMax);
        gameObject.transform.localPosition = Pos;
    }
}
```